# What is recommeded file system for a grub partition?

Tags: partitioning, grub2

What might be the recommendation file system for a grub partition, so that it will be accessed from most of linux or windows or osx systems.

Comment: Will this be a *dedicated* Grub partition? What do you need access from Windows and OSX for?

Comment: @Takkat, I need to access the configuration file `grub.cfg`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd stick to the defaults, an ext* filesystem. Personally I use ext2 because the journaling function of ext3/ext4 can make mounting the filesystem slower (observed on a flash memory stick). AFAIK journaling can be disabled for ext4, but since I was happy with ext2 I did not consider ext4 for read-only partitions like `/boot`.

- [MacFUSE](https://superuser.com/q/53533/47108) seems to work for accessing ext2/3 partitions (read+write)
- Windows supports ext2 (and ext3 without journal) with the driver from http://www.fs-driver.org/ (see also [The best choice of linux file system and software that can be accesed from Windows](https://askubuntu.com/q/19214/6969))

Avoid filesystems that do not support Linux file permissions like NTFS and FAT*. Although all files are owned by root and most of them have permissions 644, lack of proper permissions support could set inappropriate default permissions for the files.

Comment: What about fat16? My current grub partition is in fat16 system.

Comment: @Starx: see my addition.

Comment: but,ubuntu and other distros can access fat filesystems

Comment: @Starx: that's true, but FAT does not support Linux file permissions. All files on the filesystem will have the same owner and permissions. For new installations, I'd use ext*. If properly configured (mounted with `dmask=022,fmask=133,uid=0,gid=0`), filesystems like FAT are fine in the sense that it can be booted from. On my installation, `vmlinuz` cannot be read by regular users. If you're using FAT, this restriction is gone.